# c# SQL Error - Must declare scalar

Tags: c#, sql, declare, scalar

I have declared the scalar already but I am still getting the error. My code checks to see if an entry exists, if it does it updates the entry or if it does not exist it creates a new entry:

```
        try
        {
            string server = Properties.Settings.Default.SQLServer;
            string connection = "Data Source=" + server + ";Initial Catalog=Propsys;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=0925greg";
            using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connection))
            {
                cn.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from Agent WHERE ContactPerson = @" + this.contactPersonTextBox.Text, cn);
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", contactPersonTextBox.Text);
                    SqlDataReader myReader;
                    myReader = cmdCount.ExecuteReader();
                    int count = 0;
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    if (count > 0)
                    {
                        string query = "UPDATE _1Agent SET DealID = @DealID, \n" +
                                        "ContactPerson = @ContactPerson, \n" +
                                        "Address = @Address, \n" +
                                        "TaxVatNo = @TaxVatNo, \n" +
                                        "Comm = @Comm, \n" +
                                        "WorkTel = @WorkTel, \n" +
                                        "Cell = @Cell, \n" +
                                        "Fax = @Fax, \n" +
                                        "Email = @Email, \n" +
                                        "Web = @Web, \n" +
                                        "CreateDate = @CreateDate, \n" +
                                        "Notes = @Notes WHERE id = @id";
                        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query);
                        string Contact = contactPersonTextBox.Text;
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealID", txtDealNo.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", contactPersonTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addressTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaxVatNo", taxVatNoTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comm", commTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkTel", workTelTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", cellTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", faxTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", notesTextBox.Text);
                        cm.CommandText = query;
                        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Saved...", "Data Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string query1 = "INSERT INTO _1Agent (DealID, \n" +
                                        "ContactPerson, \n" +
                                        "Address, \n" +
                                        "TaxVatNo, \n" +
                                        "Comm, \n" +
                                        "WorkTel, \n" +
                                        "Cell, \n" +
                                        "Fax, \n" +
                                        "Email, \n" +
                                        "CreateDate, \n" +
                                        "Notes) VALUES ('" + txtDealNo.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + contactPersonTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + addressTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + taxVatNoTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + commTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + workTelTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + cellTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + faxTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + emailTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + notesTextBox.Text + "',\n" +
                                        "'" + DateTime.Now + "')";
                        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query1);
                        string Contact = contactPersonTextBox.Text;
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealID", txtDealNo.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", contactPersonTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", addressTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaxVatNo", taxVatNoTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comm", commTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkTel", workTelTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", cellTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fax", faxTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", emailTextBox.Text);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreateDate", DateTime.Now);
                        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", notesTextBox.Text);
                        cm.CommandText = query1;
                        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cn.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("Saved...", "Data Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                    }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the value of `this.contactPersonTextBox.Text`?

Comment: The code fails at this point: myReader = cmdCount.ExecuteReader();

Comment: You should use `ExecuteScalar` to read your `count(*)` result, there is no need to loop a reader; it always returns a single value.  Use `if exists` if you dont actually care about the count value.

Answer (score 5):

Your usage of parameter is wrong, it should be:

```
SqlCommand cmdCount = 
new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from Agent WHERE ContactPerson = @ContactPerson", cn);
```

Later you are adding the parameter correctly.

```
cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", contactPersonTextBox.Text);
```

To get the count use `SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar`, instead of using `DataReader`:

```
int count = (int) cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();
```

For the other queries, `UPDATE` and `INSERT`,  you can use a verbatim string, instead of concatenating strings over multiple lines.

```
string query = @"UPDATE _1Agent SET DealID = @DealID, 
                ContactPerson = @ContactPerson, 
                Address = @Address, 
                TaxVatNo = @TaxVatNo, 
                Comm = @Comm, 
                WorkTel = @WorkTel, 
                Cell = @Cell, 
                Fax = @Fax, 
                Email = @Email, 
                Web = @Web, 
                CreateDate = @CreateDate, 
                Notes = @Notes WHERE id = @id";
```

Other issues with the code:

- You are concatenating strings to form `INSERT` query, later you are adding parameters, follow the same convention as `UPDATE` query and then use the parameters.
- As pointed out in the other answer, you are not adding parameter`@id` value for `UPDATE` command
- **You are not specifying connection property** with your `UPDATE` and `INSERT` command:

Specify it like

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
```

- Consider enclosing `Connection` and `Command` object in [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)
  statement as it will ensure the proper disposal of unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 3):

I see a few things;

Don't use string concatenation with `@` sign for parameters. That's wrong usage. Use it like;

```
"SELECT count(*) from Agent WHERE ContactPerson = @ContactPerson"
```

and

```
cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", contactPersonTextBox.Text);
```

and use [`ExecuteScalar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get first column of the first row. Using a reader is unnecessary for this command.

Your `UPDATE` query requires `@id` value since you declare it in your command as;

```
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", yourIDvalue);
```

Your `INSERT` query, you **never** declare your parameters in your command. You just concatenate them with their values. And use [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to generate multiline strings instead of  using `\n`.

#### Please

Read more carefully about parameterized queries and how you can use them.

- [Give me parameterized SQL, or give me death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

Comment: There could be so many errors for "Must declare Scalar" in the OP, +1 for scrolling down and taking a look at the INSERT statement as well,

Comment: Okay, its working well with the existing entry location and then deciding to update or insert. But now I am getting this error: ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. When should I open the connection and then close?

Comment: @user2542289, that is because with your `INSERT` and `UPDATE` commands, you are not specifying the connection `SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query);`,  Just do `SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, cn);`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to mention parameter name in your select query

```
SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from Agent WHERE ContactPerson = @ContactPerson", cn);
cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", contactPersonTextBox.Text);
```

There are some wrong things .So you can refer **@Soner Gönül** and **@habib** answers

And change your insert query.Since you have declared paramertes but you didn't define.So change as follows

```
 string query1 = "INSERT INTO _1Agent (DealID,ContactPerson,Address,TaxVatNo, 
                     Comm, WorkTel, Cell, Fax, Email,Notes,CreateDate)
                     VALUES ( @DealID , @ContactPerson,@Address ,@TaxVatNo ,
                     @Comm,@WorkTel , @Cell,@Fax,@Email,@Notes,@CreateDate)";
```